# Admob v6.4.1 - status?

Tags: admob

I have seen following thing in many places.

> Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.

Yesterday (20th of Aug, 2014) I submit game with small traffic as experiment to see what will happen if I will use Admob v6.4.1

It works and shows ads.

I thought Google Play will block or at least I will not see ads.
Is Admob v6.4.1 compliant with Advertising ID ?

Due to deadlines it is complex to switch to play services right now. There is issue with layouts in some apps.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to use admob via the google play service library because they contain the ad ID. Ads will still work when using Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 and though we are still able to publish the updated apps with older jars, those apps are currently in violation of the Google Play store policy which states that "On August 1, 2014, new or updated apps shouldn't use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK V6.4.1 or lower.

You risk getting your game/account suspended.

According to the [official google play content policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html):

"Usage of Android advertising ID

Google Play Services version 4.0 introduced new APIs and an ID for use by advertising and analytics providers. Terms for the use of these APIs and ID are [below](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html): "